# Indexing OR AND queries MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, compound-index, logical-or

I have a requests table within my database which consists of a few fields such as "pending" to denote if a request has not been serviced, "expiry" to keep a track of the expiry time in milliseconds (Epoch), "count" which counts down to 0 every time the request is fired.

Now I search for all requests where either the request has expired OR the count has dropped to 0 AND pending is true. I am then ordering the results based on the expiry time.

I did try to create an index for this but based on the results for my explain() command, I am sure MongoDB is not using the index. Any suggestions on what should be the compound index for such a query ?

To put it in generic terms, the query is essentially (A OR B) AND C ordered by C

That's the query I built via Morphia, Java (I am new to MongoDB) ->

```
query.and(query.criteria("pending").equal(true));
query.or(query.criteria("count").equal(0), query.criteria("expiry").lessThan(System.currentTimeMillis()));
query.order("expiry");
```

Comment: Could you write down your query-object?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, its working fine now. Just in case anybody does want to know how it works, its pretty trivial. Just created an index on all the three fields in the order that I have them in the query and the explain() command seems to be using the index. :)